# Modeling Error Please help me

Tags: modeling

So I dont know what I did wrong But I am following a course to model a humain body and the teacher isn's responding to anyone for months so here is my problem. This is what is was soppose to do like you see in the second picture and the third on is what I did so how can I fix it.
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please help me im desperate

Comment: Please use a descriptive title, and avoid extraneous text like "please help", "question about" and "doubt", that is what everyone is here for. Thouroughly explaining your issue might also help get answers

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit hard to visualize without having the actual mesh, but I *think* you just have an extra loop in there.  If you just merge the points on the yellow edge here to the points to their right, you'll be pretty close to correct.

[image]

[image]

OK, then add this edge in green, delete the edge in red, and move the top endpoint of the green edge over to the right:

[image]

That should give you this edge in your reference model:

[image]

Then I think the last problem edge is the one that curves over the top of the bicep.

Comment: Okay I got It It's look like that after but It's still not the same thing

Comment: well, can you post an update of what it looks like now?  I can't visualize it in my head.

Comment: Well the picture just under yours is the one after

Comment: ok I added what I think is the next step.

Comment: Thanks you I redid all the part and I dont know what I did wrong But It worked But still Thanks